# probabilty that the students will pass

Tags: probability

The University of Metropolis requires its students to pass an examination in college-level mathematics before they can graduate. The students are given three chances to pass the exam; 61% pass it on their first attempt, 64% of those that take it a second time pass it then, and 47% of those that take it a third time pass it then. (Assume that all students who do not pass the first or second time elect to take the test again.)

What percent of the students take the test three times? (Round your answer to one decimal place.)

so basically I have to figure out what the percentage is of kids that must take the test three times. It seems to me that I have insufficient information, because I don't know how many kids take each test.

Comment: Make a decision tree.  First branch is test one.  Second branch is test two.  Those who fail both times is the answer you are after.

Comment: is there any way you can show me how to make a decision tree? I know one should look but necessarily how to input the data

Comment: I'll make one in an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a decision tree.  Can you see which value is the percentage of people who failed the first two tests?

[image]

Comment: .36? how did you arrive at the other numbers?

Comment: On the first test, there is a .61 chance of passing.  So you're done.  There is a .39 chance you will fail.  At which point you take it again, with a .64 chance of passing and .36 chance of failing.  So there is a $.39*.64=.2496$ chance you will Fail then Pass.  And there is a $.39*.36=.1404$ chance you will Fail both times.

Comment: so you would multiply .53 by .47? to arrive at 0.2491?

Comment: No.  14.04% is the answer.  The only people who take it 3 times are the people who both A)Fail Test 1 and B)Fail Test 2.  Which is $.39*.36$